# 2 different Wordpress blogs with same URL on Magento multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, magento, multisite

I have a magento multisite with 2 tld.

a) **domain-a.com** (Wordpress files located in /blog)

b) **domain-b.com** (Wordpress files located in /blog_b)

On domain-a.com i have a Wordpress blog installed on domain-a.com/blog

I want to do that same thing on domain-b.com/blog, but it should show other Wordpress installation located in /blog_b

When i change website address in Wordpress located in /blog_b to /blog, it shows the Wordpress installation in /blog and not /blog_b

I do not want to run Wordpress Multisite, nor do i want to integrate Wordpress and Magento.

I guess i need to make a change in .htaccess so when i visit domain-b.com/blog it shows Wordpress install located in /blog_b?

Hope you understand what i am trying to archieve here.

Comment: NOTE: domain-a.com and domain-b.com share same root foler

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple you could place an index page in /blog, with a frame or something that redirects to /blog_b. But with .htaccess you can do the following:

```
# Redirect /blog to /blog_b
Redirect 301 /blog http://domain-b.com/blog_b
```

EDIT:
Right, I did not think about normal requests to domain-a.com/blog. I am not sure, but I think this could work. It will check if the requested domain is domain-b.com, and if the requested subfolder is /blog. If so, forward to /blog_b. Just a suggestion that might not work, I can't test this right now, sorry.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-b.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /blog_b [L]
```

Comment: If i place that code in .htaccess, then it will also redirect domain-a.com/blog to domain-a.com/blog_b?

Comment: Right, I've updated my answer. Maybe someone else will need to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing a Wordpress multisite instead. I can not say if your answer worked, because i went ahead with other solution first.
Thanks anyway :)